# Useraccounts updated to Useraccounts:iron-routing

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts

updated my meteor app and had useraccounts on it and it suddenly told me to install the useraccounts:iron-routing to use it with Iron Router...

Installed the package and now its telling me

```
W20150818-19:23:20.744(-6)? (STDERR) Error: changePwd route configured but enablePasswordChange set to false!
```

and won't start my app, but my AccountsTemplates.configure({ has all seted to true... here is the code:

```
//Routes
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('changePwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('enrollAccount');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('forgotPwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('resetPwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signUp');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('verifyEmail');

// Options


AccountsTemplates.configure({


    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    showForgotPasswordLink: true,
    overrideLoginErrors: true,
    enablePasswordChange: true,
    sendVerificationEmail: false,

    //enforceEmailVerification: true,
    //confirmPassword: true,
    //continuousValidation: false,
    //displayFormLabels: true,
    //forbidClientAccountCreation: false,
    //formValidationFeedback: true,
    //homeRoutePath: '/',
    //showAddRemoveServices: false,
    //showPlaceholders: true,

    negativeValidation: true,
    positiveValidation:true,
    negativeFeedback: false,
    positiveFeedback:true,

    // Privacy Policy and Terms of Use
    //privacyUrl: 'privacy',
    //termsUrl: 'terms-of-use',
});

AccountsTemplates.configure({
    showLabels: true,
    negativeValidation: true,
    negativeFeedback: true
});


AccountsTemplates.addField({
    _id: "username",
    type: "text",
    displayName: "username",
    required: true,
    minLength: 5,
});

AccountsTemplates.removeField('email');
AccountsTemplates.addField({
    _id: 'email',
    type: 'email',
    required: true,
    displayName: "email",
    re: /.+@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/,
    errStr: 'Invalid email',
});

AccountsTemplates.removeField('password');
AccountsTemplates.addField({
    _id: 'password',
    type: 'password',
    required: true,
    minLength: 6,
    re: /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/,
    errStr: 'At least 1 digit, 1 lowercase and 1 uppercase',
});
```

any help?

Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving AccountTemplates.configure BEFORE AccountTemplates.configureRoute in your file. Also make sure whatever file those are in is accessible to both the client and server.

Comment: Thanks this made it work, I just took AccountTemplates.configureRoute i to the bottom of the code as you suggested