# Iron Router user accounts error on upgrade

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, user-accounts

Upon upgrade to Meteor 1.1.0.3, I am getting this error on load:

```
W20150903-07:55:45.040(1)? (STDERR)
W20150903-07:55:45.040(1)? (STDERR) /Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.rrtb94++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150903-07:55:45.041(1)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20150903-07:55:45.041(1)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20150903-07:55:45.049(1)? (STDERR) Error: changePwd route configured but enablePasswordChange set to false!
W20150903-07:55:45.049(1)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].AccountsTemplates.configureRoute (packages/useraccounts:iron-routing/lib/core.js:113:1)
W20150903-07:55:45.049(1)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/config/at_config.js:2:19
W20150903-07:55:45.049(1)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/config/at_config.js:34:3
W20150903-07:55:45.049(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/me/code/js/meteor/ssc/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150903-07:55:45.049(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150903-07:55:45.049(1)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.rrtb94++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150903-07:55:45.050(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/me/code/js/meteor/ssc/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
```

My `router.js` file had this at the top and worked fine before:

```
 AccountTemplates.configure  AccountTemplates.configure Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
});
```

I have followed advice e.g. [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085583/useraccounts-updated-to-useraccountsiron-routing) but am still getting the error.

My current `router.js` file now has allsorts in it to try and fix the problem and I have tried to order and reorder it various times. The whole file looks like this:

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    showForgotPasswordLink: true,
    overrideLoginErrors: true,
    enablePasswordChange: true,
    sendVerificationEmail: false,
});


Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/user/:_username', {
  name: 'user_profile',
  data: function() { return Meteor.user();} 
});

Router.route('/create', function() {
  this.render('createEvent');
}, {
  name: 'create'
});

Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  if (!Meteor.userId()) {
    // if the user is not logged in, render the Login template
    this.render('home');
  } else {
    // otherwise don't hold up the rest of hooks or our route/action function
    // from running
    this.next();
  }
}, {
  only: ['create']
});

Router.route('/insert', function() {
  this.render('insertEvent');
});

Router.route('/events/:slug', {
  name: 'event',
  data: function() { return Events.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});}
});

Router.route('/useremail', function() {
    this.render('userEmail');
}, {
    name: 'userEmail'
});


Router._filters = {
  hasCompletedProfile: function() {
    if(!this.ready()) return;
    var user = Meteor.user();
    if (user && ! userProfileComplete(user)){
      this.render('userEmail');
    } else {
      this.next();
    } 
  }, 
}; 

// copied from Telesc.pe router.js
filters = Router._filters;
Router.onBeforeAction(filters.hasCompletedProfile);

Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('changePwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('enrollAccount');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('forgotPwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('resetPwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signUp');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('verifyEmail');
```

What can I do?

Comment: From what you're showing you're setting `enablePasswordChange` to `true` before doing `AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('changePwd')`, so that should be good.  Are you sure you don't have code in another file that is also doing AccountsTemplates configuration?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you update your question to show the entire router.js file?

Comment: Yes and the error too.

Comment: Do you have a file located at `/lib/config/at_config.js` that contains AccountsTemplates configuration?

Comment: Yes, the problem was in there. I should've seen that. Thanks for your attention!